# How to make font rendering auto-adjust to monitor orientation changing

Tags: fonts, orientation

I encounter what appears like bad anti-aliasing or something similar, in the built in PDF viewer and in browsers alike, when switching to portrait mode. All texts just appear oddly fuzzy. Is there a more integrated way of fixing this up so that whenever you change monitor orientation, fonts appear clearly?

I have seen solutions (or should I say partial solutions) mentioned [via this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078286/better-sub-pixel-rendering-of-fonts-when-monitor-is-in-the-portrait-mode), but would like to be able to switch the monitor orientation now and then depending on the task at hand, without running a [multitude of setup commands every time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561443/setting-different-subpixel-rendering-on-different-monitors).

I assume this requires integration with the setup screen where display orientation is controlled (Settings → Devices → Displays) in the default Settings app.

I know this might be more like a missing feature request than something that can be done right now without forking the source, but just in case ...

If there's a way, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

I'd starting using udev. I concur that this should go as bug. But until Canonical is moving you may create an udev rule (on a monitor change event) that updates the font color rendering from RGB to vRGB. 
This might you give a hint : [autorandr](https://github.com/apiraino/autorandr)