# Two monitors with different subpixel rendering pixel order?

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, fonts

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I believe that my two monitors use different orders for the pixels and so I can only ever get fonts to look great on one or the other.

I found this previous answer [Setting different subpixel rendering on different monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561443/setting-different-subpixel-rendering-on-different-monitors) but it is old enough that I wanted to know if there is any better method. I don't see much luck in dconf-editor, I see the rgba-order folder but no indication that it is aware of there being a spanned desktop over multiple monitors.

Comment: Can you verify with the makers of the monitors what you think about the pixels?